# Lookat targeted enemy and orbit

Tags: unity-game-engine

Previously I had a script that I could look at a player but only when I had the Tab buttoned pressed down but could not cycle through enemies or anything. Looking all day for answers I came by this and decided it would be great I can now find things tagged enemies and cycle though them but I have not been able to figure out a way to lookat the enemy and stay looking at them and be able to move around them in a circle.

```
public class debug : MonoBehaviour
 {

 public List<Transform> targets;
 public Transform selectedTarget;
 public string targetTag = "Enemy";
 private Transform myTransform;

 //Use this for initialization
 void Start()
 {
     targets = new List<Transform>();
     selectedTarget = null;
     myTransform = transform;
     AddAllEnemies();
 }

 public void AddAllEnemies()
 {
     GameObject[] go = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(targetTag);
     foreach (GameObject enemy in go)
     {
         AddTarget(enemy.transform);
     }
 }

 public void AddTarget(Transform enemy)
 {
     targets.Add(enemy);
 }

 /*private void SortTargetsByDistance()
 {
     targets.Sort(delegate (Transform t1, Transform t2) {
         return (Vector3.Distance(t1.position, myTransform.position).CompareTo)
             (Vector3.Distance(t2.position, myTransform.position));
     });
 } */
 private void SortTargetsByDistance()
 {
     targets.RemoveAll(target => target == null);
     targets.Sort(delegate (Transform t1, Transform t2) {
         return (Vector3.Distance(t1.position, myTransform.position).CompareTo)
             (Vector3.Distance(t2.position, myTransform.position));
     });
 }

 private void TargetEnemy()
 {
     if (selectedTarget == null)
     {
         SortTargetsByDistance();
         selectedTarget = targets[0];
     }
     else
     {
         int index = targets.IndexOf(selectedTarget);
         if (index < targets.Count - 1)
         {
             index++;
         }
         else
         {
             index = 0;
         }

         selectedTarget = targets[index];
     }
 }

 //Update is called once per frame
 void Update()
 {
     if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab))
     {
         TargetEnemy();
     }
     }
 }
```

I am trying to use `transform.LookAt(TargetEnemy);` in void update but I get an error saying cannot convert from method group to transform. Im really stuck on this now any help is appreciated.

Edit: I am a big dummy I used `transform.LookAt(selectedTarget);` instead and the character for a split second will turn and lookat the enemy. Now i need to keep the player looking at the target and move around them.

Comment: Well you made edit as I was typing my answer, oh well. So now your problem is you need it to keep looking at `selectedTarget`? How often do you call `transform.LookAt(selectedTarget)`? Is there anything else modifying the rotation?

Comment: Yes my problem is that the player does not keep looking at the enemy. I was thinking that if the player did keep looking i could easily just use my character controller to move back forward etc.. expecting weird animations. what am i missing that is making it that as soon as i move the character stops looking at the enemy?

Answer (score 1):

[`Transform.LookAt`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html)

You need to pass it a `Transform`, not `void`.

```cs
TargetEnemy();
transform.LookAt(selectedTarget);
```

Alternatively, you can make `TargetEnemy()` return a `Transform`.:

```cs
private Transform TargetEnemy()
 {
     /* stuff */

     return selectedTarget;
 }
```

```cs
transform.LookAt(TargetEnemy());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply as soon as I made this post I noticed that error and made an edit but it was to late it seems. The player now looks at the target but if i try and move it doesn't stay locked on to which ever target.

Answer (score 1):

Hello thanks to everyone that looked and thank @SonicBlue22 for your answer I figured it out after a couple more hours.

```
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Tab))
        {
            TargetEnemy();
            transform.LookAt(selectedTarget);
        }

        if (selectedTarget != null)
        {
            transform.LookAt(selectedTarget);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Q))
        {
            selectedTarget = null;
            return;
        }

    }

}
```